# Combinational SUM Max 5 factors C++

Tags: c++

I have an issue related with getting the sum of a combination of 25 numbers.
Program shows the sum, but I cannot limit the factor to 5.  where the sum = 100.

It shows, too many arrays and with more than 5 factors where the sum "K" is getting 100.
Number cannot repeat.

Here is the code:

```
// C++ implementation of the approach 
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// Function to find all unique combination of 
// given elements such that their sum is K 
void unique_combination(int l, int sum, int K, 
                        vector<int>& local, vector<int>& A) 
{ 
    // If a unique combination is found 
    if (sum == K) { 
        cout << "{"; 
        for (int i = 0; i < local.size(); i++) { 
            if (i != 0) 
                cout << " "; 
            cout << local[i]; 
            if (i != local.size() - 1) 
                cout << ", "; 
        } 
        cout << "}" << endl; 
        return; 
    } 

    // For all other combinations 
    for (int i = l; i < A.size(); i++) { 

        // Check if the sum exceeds K 
        if (sum + A[i] > K) 
            continue; 

        // Check if it is repeated or not 
        if (i and A[i] == A[i - 1] and i > l) 
            continue; 

        // Take the element into the combination 
        local.push_back(A[i]); 

        // Recursive call 
        unique_combination(i + 1, sum + A[i], 
                           K, local, A); 

        // Remove element from the combination 
        local.pop_back(); 
    } 
} 

// Function to find all combination 
// of the given elements 
void Combination(vector<int> A, int K) 
{ 
    // Sort the given elements 
    sort(A.begin(), A.end()); 

    // To store combination 
    vector<int> local; 

    unique_combination(0, 0, K, local, A); 
} 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> A = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25 }; 

    int K = 100; 

    // Function call 
    Combination(A, K); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Would you please check and let me know where is my error?

Thank you in advance.

For example Results that I get:

> {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10,  13,  15,  17} 
>   {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10,  14,  15,  16}
>   {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10,  20,  25} 
>   {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10,  21,  24}

But as you can see array has more than 5 elements (has 12 or 13 for example)

Comment: You have not written any code that limits the size.

Comment: What did you find out using your debugger? In what line does the actual behavior differ from your expectation the first time?

Comment: @molbdnilo could you please show me how to limit the size? I have tried with an if but I got too many errors,

Comment: Post your attempt, and someone might tell you what's wrong with it.